# DropDownList in mvc3 don't recognize selecteditem in selectlist

Tags: text, new-operator, selectlist, selectlistitem

I'm trying to send SelectedList to view via ViewBag and on controller I have set the selected item this is controller

```
   ViewData["aaa"]= new SelectList(new []{new SelectListItem { Text = "1", Value = "1" },
 new SelectListItem { Text = "2", Value = "2"},
 new SelectListItem { Text = "25", Value = "25" },
 new SelectListItem { Text = "50", Value = "50" },
 new SelectListItem { Text = "100", Value = "100" },
 new SelectListItem { Text = "1000", Value = "1000" }}, "Text", "Value", "100" );
```

view part

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m1 => m1.Sobe,(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["aaa"])
```

and i get this html

```
    <select data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Sobe must be a number." data-val-required="The Sobe field is required." id="Sobe" name="Sobe"><option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="25">25</option>
<option value="50">50</option>
<option value="100">100</option>
<option value="1000">1000</option>
</select>
```

that means without any selection. I don' understand, please any help

Comment: And I know it will work if i change DropDownListFor to DropDownLIst and set different name from property, but then i cannot get back values

Answer (score 0):

Html helper selects item that is found in

> m1.Sobe

. If m1.Sobe is 0, then nothing would be selected.

Html helper ignores selected item in "SelectList"

Comment: It is not a case, i just define that value explicitlly. I found solution to change dropdownlist name, but i than cannot databind data to html? is there any work around for that?

Comment: names must be identical to return data to the model

Comment: Yes i know that but then mvc willnot show selected value if i put name same as property. this is article http://mattpenner.info/2010/02/02/mvc-bug-with-default-dropdownlist-or-listbox-html-helpers/#comment-504